# Can I backup multiple mysql databases (All InnoDB) without using mysqldump and just using file/folder backup

Tags: mysql, database-backups, mysql-backup

Is there any way where I can take a backup of some files/folders to take the backup of all my Mysql databases. I am using Acronis Cloud Backup tool and I dont find any option where I can backup mysql database. It is either Drive/Folder or entire machine. Need an approach without using mysqldump. Instead I am looking at directory/files backup

Also it is NOT a linux machine so cron & shell script cannot be used. It is windows 2016 server.

What is the best approach to backup multiple mysql databases which in emergency can be restored reasonably fast and accurately.

Thanks

Kalpak

Comment: For CRON think Task Scheduler ... for Shell Script think PowerShell

Comment: MySQL is a real database. It has the ablility to recover databases to the exact point of failure if needed. But only if you use the features provided. A file backup is in no way a replacement

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the databases are not so small (Some are nearly a GB each). And taking a dump using mysqldump and then using powershells and Task Scheduler, wont it take time than a simple folder copy.

Comment: Is database always in use?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, About the feature, how do I enable/use it. Also how do I take this backup on cloud (a place not on the server so that in case of catastrophic failure I have something to restore. We had a RAID corruption last month and we did loose some data in that

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Mainly during day time. Night time I can take it offline for an hour or so

Comment: Doing a file copy, you may get lucky with a restore, or worse, you may thing you got lucky until a week later people start seeing coruptions. Look at hot backups and incremental backups etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Appreciate your help. Will look into hotbackups and incremental backup and get back to you in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup the complete folder

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0
```

And after reinstalling you copy all folder/files back.

I had to do it last week, so i am sure that it works, but you need **all files**.

And this is not incremnetal.

Comment: A small question. Will the database files be locked and cause the database backup failure. Also are there any issues while restoring the database.

Comment: the server has to be stopped. and no pending transactiios open, this will cause also very much space

Comment: Ok. Appreciate your help.